# Convert a SharePoint Online Classic Team site to SharePoint Online Modern Communications Showcase site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, rename, modern-experience, communication-site

Possible to rename an SPO Team site?

If not, possible to Convert a SharePoint Online Classic Team site to a SharePoint Online Modern Communications Showcase site?

Answer (score 1):

There is no migration tool to achieve this. You can use [this](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Solutions/SharePoint.UIExperience.Scanner) tool to get a report of sites, lists, libraries, etc. which will not work as expected when using the SharePoint "modern" user interface experiences.

In [this](https://nathanwellsblog.com/2017/07/23/how-and-when-to-adopt-the-modern-ui-in-sharepoint-part-12/) article it's explained how to adopt the Modern UI.